# GPS beacons sending data continuously to a server ?

Tags: google-maps, gps, gpsd

I want to know more about GPS beacons ? How can I configure them to send the location (longitude + latitude ) to a particular web server , after a configurable time period? Who are the good GPS beacons in the market?

Actually I want to develop a system which can send longitude and latitude to a particular web server and I can show that location on a website using google maps.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a rescue beacon product I don't think you will be able to modify them without a great deal of effort.

If you are asking how you would setup your own beacon, we probably need to know more to help you...  Do you have a net connected system which has GPS position data available? Maybe you want to setup a smartphone to be a "beacon"